# Закрытие пула из таска. Корректно ли это?

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте. В логике приложения возникла такая ситуация: у пула после проверки некоторых условий вызывается `shutdownNow()` в таске, засабмиченном в этот пул. Хочется узнать, корректно ли так поступать и какие неприятности могут произойти, если так реализовано?
Спасибо.

Comment: мне кажется странный вопрос, откуда нам знать как лучше твоему приложению? ты же сам пишешь закрытие потока по условиям, просто логируй все

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не очень хорошо в плане *дизайна* программы - таск, отправленный в пул, ничего не должен знать о самом пуле и, тем более, не должен приостанавливать выполнение других тасков. *Т.е, метод, конечно имеет право на существование, но за такое я, например, бью по рукам :)*

Более корректный способ - иметь некоторый **координирующий поток** *(пусть даже и основной)*, который в случае выполнения определенных условий может вызвать `shutdownNow`.

Еще одно подтверждение моих слов - `shutdownNow()` возвращает текущий список невыполненных заданий (`List<Runnable>`) и код таска совершенно не должен решать, **что с ними делать дальше.** *Это совершенно другая область ответственности и смешивать их здесь - плохой тон.*

#### Update

---

Вы сейчас не зря сказали слово **закручено**. И обычно в таких случаях есть несколько вариантов - идти по пути наименьшего сопротивления, и **оставить все как есть,** или же заняться *рефакторингом кода, уменьшением связанности и `decoupling'ом` задач.* Первый способ обычно ведет к проблемам при длительной разработке, когда кривые решения выплывают на поверхность где-то в другом месте.

У вас пример такого "выплыва" уже присутствует - **что вы собираетесь делать с тасками, которые все еще выполняются в пуле?**

Таск подразумевает реализацию в стиле, приближенному к функциональному. *Получил данные на вход, отработал, вернул результат.* И наверняка можно как-то переработать вашу логику, чтобы это условие выполнялось. Могу в качестве пищи для размышлений порекомендовать почитать про [**подход MapReduce.**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

Comment: так закручено что условия необходимые для закрытия пула могут проверены только в самом таске  (

Comment: @Vladimir Ответил вам апдейтом.

Comment: Просто пусть таск, обнаруживший условие закрытия, выставит флаг.

Answer (score 2):

Делать [shutdownNow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) из таска совершенно точно не валидно. В некоторых случаях можно решиться сделать просто [shutdown](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29), чтобы исключить возможность запуска новых. Но даже тогда, как уже говорилось, это не является хорошей идеей.

Вместо этого, если действительно надо всё прибить, надо запустить последовательность остановки, которая бы освободила все ресурсы и позволила таскам завершиться самим собой, а уже после этого можно шатдаунить (только не из такси и не из потока самой таски) весь пул.

PS: честно говоря, не совсем ясно, как MapReduce тут поможет делу.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Ну `mapreduce` здесь просто как иллюстрация функционального подхода, который спокойно скейлится в случае многопоточных приложений. Просто, если сразу же писать все более-менее адекватно, то и вопросов про `shutdownNow` из таска возникать не должно. *Да и лично мне в свое время `mapreduce` помог неплохо кое-чего осознать в `concurrent` области.*

Расскажите кстати, почему `shutdownNow` именно **не валиден**, т.к, честно говоря, я не очень в курсе происходящего внутри, а в `openjdk` лезть не хочется.

Comment: ... Очень много переделывать ... 
А если я все таки останавлюсь на том, как мне посоветовали. Установка volatile флага из таска и проверка этого флага в другом потоке, и в случае если флаг true - обычный shutdown пула, Очередь в нем заданная, маленькая и таски завершатся сами собой. Такой подход приемлем ?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать  shutdownNow плох тем, что он делает interrupt. Почитайте javadoc, там ведь всё написано. Сам по себе interrupt должен использовать только если вы точно знаете, что вы интерраптите, а иначе это бессмыслица. Зато, этот интеррапт может что-нибудь сломать и где-то что-то пойдёт не по плану. Например, нормальный шатдаун-флоу может обломиться и получится какая-нибудь фигня. Зато просто shutdown только помечает пул как более непригодный для выполнения и все потоки будут завершаться по мере выполнения тасков, а новые таски запустить уже будет нельзя.

Comment: @Vladimir такой подход приемлем, вот только как вы будете в другом потоке проверять этот флаг не ясно. Вот если бы вы ждали wait на чём-нибудь и проверяли флаг (уже тогда не волатильный).